# Extend scala class that extends ordered

Tags: inheritance, scala, covariance

I'm having trouble extending a base class that extends Ordered[Base]. My derived class can't extend Ordered[Derived] so can't be used as a key in a TreeMap. If I create a TreeMap[Base] and then just override compare in Derived that works but it's not what I want. I would like to be able to have the derived class as a key. Is there a way around this?

```
case class A(x: Int) extends Ordered[A] {
  def compare(that: A) = x.compare(that.x)
}

// Won't compile
//  case class B(val y : Int) extends A(1) with Ordered[B] {
//    def compare(that: B) = x.compare(that.x) match {
//      case 0 => y.compare(that.y)
//      case res => res
//    }
//  }

// Compiles but can't be used to define a TreeMap key
case class B(y: Int) extends A(1) {
  override def compare(that: A) = that match {
    case b: B => x.compare(b.x) match {
      case 0 => y.compare(b.y)
      case res => res
    }
    case _: A => super.compare(that)
  }
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  TreeMap[B, Int]() // Won't compile
}
```

**Edit**

[This discussion](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.scala/2007-03/msg00128.html) on the scala mailing list seems to be very relevant but it loses me a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a type conversion from B to Ordered[B]:

```
class OrderedB(me : B) extends Ordered[B]{
    def compare(that: B) = me compare that
}
collection.immutable.TreeMap.empty[B, Int](new OrderedB(_))
```

I think B has always to be a subtype of A which implies Order[A] whoes type A is invariant. It cannot define a second compare method to implement Order[B] with the same type errasure as the compare method from Ordered[A].

Alternatively you can define an implicit type versions from B to Ordered[B]:

```
implicit def orderedA2orderedB[B <: A with Ordered[A]](b : B) : Ordered[B] = b.asInstanceOf[Ordered[B]]
collection.immutable.TreeMap[B, Int]()
```

This should be valid. I'm not aware of a way to express this in the type system without casts.

Comment: Thanks for the help Thomas. I was hoping there might be some Scala magic I had missed that allowed this to work. Without resorting to essentially passing in a comparator.

Is it just me or does this seem very limiting, and quite annoying? Or is it just to be expected?

Comment: When working with Ordered[T], you're generally supposed to use a the <% relationship to request that you want a view that orders the object. If you don't then types such as Int (which don't extend AnyRef, so they can't implement any traits) won't work with your container either.

Note that this answer only deals with Scala 2.7

Comment: @Dave - I've added a implicit type conversion version. It is not perfect as a cast is needed.

Comment: @Ken - Could you add an answer? I don't understand where the view bound fits in.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for your answer. The cast isn't pretty but it works great and by putting the conversion in B's companion object it shouldn't even be visible to people using it. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The trait `Ordered` takes a parameter. A type parameter, granted, but it works just like any other parameter. When you extend it twice, in the base class and in the subclass, you are not "importing" two versions of `Ordered`. Instead, linearization of classes takes place, and you import it only once. For that reason, you cannot pass two different parameters to it.

Now, there is a reason why `TreeMap` does not require a `subclass` of `Ordered`, just a conversion from your class to an `Ordered` of it. It is precisely to make such things possible. Instead of extending these things directly, you should implicits for them:

```
scala> class A(val x: Int)
defined class A

scala> class B(x : Int, val y : Int) extends A(x)
defined class B

scala> import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

scala> class AOrd(a: A) extends Ordered[A] {
     |   def compare(that: A) = a.x.compare(that.x)
     | }
defined class AOrd

scala> object AOrd {
     | implicit def toAOrd(a: A) = new AOrd(a)
     | }
defined module AOrd

scala> class BOrd(b: B) extends Ordered[B] {
     |   def compare(that: B) = b.x.compare(that.x) match {
     |     case 0 => b.y.compare(that.y)
     |     case res => res
     |   }
     | }
defined class BOrd

scala> object BOrd {
     | implicit def toBOrd(b: B) = new BOrd(b)
     | }
defined module BOrd

scala> import AOrd._
import AOrd._

scala> import BOrd._
import BOrd._

scala> TreeMap[B, Int]()
res1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[B,Int] = Map()
```

Comment: How do you support natural ordering for A and B? Always importing AOrd._ & BOrd._ is not nice and every a1 : A < a2 : A will result in 2 instances of AOrd.

Comment: How do you produce these nice interpreter session listings?

Comment: The scala interpreter: `$scala`.

Comment: @Thomas: It will result in two new instance of AOrd, which will be immediately garbage collected, unless JIT optimizes the new instances away. Short lived objects happens all the time with Scala, and JVM is very good at optimizing it.  As an alternative you could define the methods on A and override on B, without extending Ordered (you still need AOrd&BOrd for sort, however). Unfortunately, Ordered is not contra-variant, which makes it impossible to use A's ordering for B.

Comment: @ziggystar: I call "scala", type the code, copy&paste do Stack Overflow, select it, and then click on the "code" button.

Comment: As of 2013 and Scala 2.10, is there a more sane solution to this problem? Any hope?

Comment: @qertoip Yes. Nowdays you use `Ordering` type class instead of extending `Ordered`.

Answer (score 2):

You could put an implicit Ordering[B] in scope somewhere, like this:

```
  object BOrdering extends Ordering[B] {
    def compare(a: B, b: B) = a.compare(b)
  }
  implicit val bo = BOrdering
  TreeMap[B, Int]() // Now it works!
```

---

**EDIT**: This is only in Scala 2.8 (thanks, Ken)